# Solr data type corresponding to cql decimal

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql3

what is the solr type corresponding to Cassandra's decimal data type?

```
CREATE TABLE demo_table (
 cost decimal
)
```

what should be the corresponding data type for solr?

```
<field name="cost" type="XXX" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most-recent DSE 4.6 doc [Mapping of Solr types](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html) seems to indicate that the Solr `BCDStrField` type should be used to map to the CQL `decimal` type:

```
Solr Type    | CQL type
-------------------------------------------------------
BCDStrField  | ascii, decimal,text, varchar, varint
```

Although, the [Solr documentation on that type](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr) seems to indicate that `BCDStrField` is deprecated and will be removed with Solr 5.0.  That states you should use the `TrieIntField` type instead.

Are you using DSE?  Or Cassandra with Solr on your own?  If you're using DSE I'd stick with the `BCDStrField` for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DSE 4.6 try the resources autogeneration and you will get it created for you:

[Auto generation of resources](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchAutoCore.html)

Currently there is no obvious choice. But DSE is mapping decimal to a String equivalent type.

Comment: thanks for sharing the link. I was not aware about such a great utility. Will definitely look into this.